# How to get the new latitude and longitude cordinates from android

Tags: android, gps

**How i am getting location details:**

```
AppLocationService appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getApplicationContext());

Location nwLocation= appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
nwLocation.getLatitude();
nwLocation.getLongitude();
```

---

***What is happening since my code has llast known location .... its giving me the last location that was updated say now its evening. its giving me the location updated during morning***

### What i want:: how can i make a fresh network request to get the current location at my position

---

**AppLocationService.java**

```
public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 0;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 0;

    public AppLocationService(Context context) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public Location getLocation(String provider) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                    MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                return location;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know its not good, But I also facing the same issue before, at that time I call method which gives me current location two times. First time it returns last known location and second time it returns current location. I am also eager to know how to get current location in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is registering to receive location updates and also returns the last known location. What happens is expected because you didn't wait to receive an updated one.

Once the method "onLocationChanged" was called by the system you'll have the new one. You can then send a broadcast from the service.

You are trying to get the current location in a synchronous mode which is not possible as it takes some time to lookup the updated one.

Comment: How to explicitly call `onLocationChanged` ?

Comment: You are not calling it, the system does once it has an updated location. You only have to wait for it and send to the right activity/fragment/service that is waiting for it.

Comment: HOw to make the  system update it again using my class above i, can wait using thread delay

Comment: That's automatically done by the system. One of the parameters passed to requestLocationUpdates is the update interval.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason why you aren't getting updated location information quickly is that you're relying on the NETWORK_PROVIDER.

You should instead use this

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `onLocationChanged` method and get the longitude and latitude from the parametr location

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = new Location(location);
    latitude=mCurrentLocation .getLatitude();
    longitude=mCurrentLocation .getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to call Explicitly `onLocationChanged`

```
public void locationlist()
     {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    50, 0, this);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
              System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
              onLocationChanged(location);

            } else {}
         if(location == null)
         {

         }
         else{
             lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
             lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
         }

     }
```

now call the method locationlist where you want like in a timer.